# LDBL_MAX: Why does long double value print so many digits?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, double, long-integer

```
printf("Unit \"long double\" -> %i bytes -> range %Lf - %Lf.\n",\
                        sizeof(long double), LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);
```

returns

> Unit "long double" -> 16 bytes -> range 0.000000 -
> 1189731495357231765021263853030970205169063322294624200440323733891737005522970722616410290336528882853545697807495577314427443153670288434198125573853743678673593200706973263201915918282961524365529510646791086614311790632169778838896134786560600399148753433211454911160088679845154866512852340149773037600009125479393966223151383622417838542743917838138717805889487540575168226347659235576974805113725649020884855222494791399377585026011773549180099796226026859508558883608159846900235645132346594476384939859276456284579661772930407806609229102715046085388087959327781622986827547830768080040150694942303411728957777100335714010559775242124057347007386251660110828379119623008469277200965153500208474470792443848545912886723000619085126472111951361467527633519562927597957250278002980795904193139603021470997035276467445530922022679656280991498232083329641241038509239184734786121921697210543484287048353408113042573002216421348917347174234800714880751002064390517234247656004721768096486107994943415703476320643558624207443504424380566136017608837478165389027809576975977286860071487028287955567141404632615832623602762896316173978484254486860609948270867968048078702511858930838546584223040908805996294594586201903766048446790926002225410530775901065760671347200125846406957030257138960983757998926954553052368560758683179223113639519468850880771872104705203957587480013143131444254943919940175753169339392366881856189129931729104252921236835159922322050998001677102784035360140829296398115122877768135706045789343535451696539561254048846447169786893211671087229088082778350518228857646062218739702851655083720992349483334435228984751232753726636066213902281264706234075352071724058665079518217303463782631353393706774901950197841690441824738063162828586857741432581165364040218402724913393320949219498422442730427019873044536620350262386957804682003601447291997123095530057206141866974852846856186514832715974481203121946751686379343096189615107330065552421485195201762858595091051839472502863871632494167613804996319791441870254302706758495192008837915169401581740046711477877201459644461175204059453504764721807975761111720846273639279600339670470037613374509553184150073796412605047923251661354841291884211340823015473304754067072818763503617332908005951896325207071673904547777129682265206225651439919376804400292380903112437912614776255964694221981375146967079446870358004392507659451618379811859392049544036114915310782251072691486979809240946772142727012404377187409216756613634938900451232351668146089322400697993176017805338191849981933008410985993938760292601390911414526003720284872132411955424282101831204216104467404621635336900583664606591156298764745525068145003932941404131495400677602951005962253022823003631473824681059648442441324864573137437595096416168048024129351876204668135636877532814675538798871771836512893947195335061885003267607354388673368002074387849657014576090349857571243045102038730494854256702479339322809110526041538528994849203991091946129912491633289917998094380337879522093131466946149705939664152375949285890960489916121944989986384837022486672249148924678410206183364627416969576307632480235587975245253737035433882960862753427740016333434055083537048507374544819754722228975281083020898682633020285259923084168054539687911418297629988964576482765287504562854924265165217750799516259669229114977788962356670956627138482018191348321687995863652637620978285070099337294396784639879024914514222742527006363942327998483976739987154418554201562244154926653014515504685489258620276085761837129763358761215382565129633538141663949516556000264159186554850057052611431952919918807954522394649627635630178580896692226406235382898535867595990647008385687123810329591926494846250768992258419305480763620215089022149220528069842018350840586938493815498909445461977893029113576516775406232278298314033473276603952231603422824717528181818844304880921321933550869873395861276073670866652375555675803171490108477320096424318780070008797346032906278943553743564448851907191616455141155761939399690767415156402826543664026760095087523945507341556135867933066031744720924446513532366647649735400851967040771103640538150073486891798364049570606189535005089840913826869535090066783324472578712196604415284924840041850932811908963634175739897166596000759487800619164094854338758520657116541072260996288150123144377944008749301944744330784388995701842710004808305012177123560622895076269042856800047718893158089358515593863176652948089031267747029662545110861548958395087796755464137944895960527975209874813839762578592105756284401759349324162148339565350189196811389091843795734703269406342890087805846940352453479398080674273236297887100867175802531561302356064878709259865288416350972529537091114317204887747405539054009425375424119317944175137064689643861517718849867010341532542385911089624710885385808688837777258648564145934262121086647588489260031762345960769508849149662444156604419552086811989770240.000000

Maybe this is a dumb question, but is this really the max value a `long double` can hold? (The sheer magnitude blows my mind). Perhaps I am making some silly error and C is throwing out a garbage value at me?

I am compiling the code using 64 bit gcc on Linux.

Comment: I have removed your follow-up question, because it wasn't really relevant to your problem and might derail the conversation to speculation.

Comment: @user694733 no issues, i should have asked about long float in a separate question anyway. thx!

Comment: @pmg: No, it is not, all of the digits are correct. As long as the C implementation is using correct binary-decimal and decimal-binary conversions, there is no reason to regard the digits they produce as garbage.

Comment: Is this a question on just admiration of 64-bit computing's potential ?

Comment: `%i` is not the correct format specifier for `sizeof` as itevaluates to type `size_t` which might be larger than an `int´. This might result in messing up the remaining parameters. You should use `%zu` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That number is exactly 2<sup>16,384</sup>−2<sup>16,320</sup>. (It is printed correctly; I checked all digits.) It is the largest finite value representable in the IEEE-754 scheme using a 15-bit exponent and a 64-bit significand:

- With 15 bits, the exponent range is −16,382 to +16,383.
- With 64 bits, the maximum value of the significand (scaled for the [1, 2) normal range) is 2<sup>0</sup>+2<sup>−1</sup>+2<sup>−2</sup>+…+2<sup>−63</sup> = 2−2<sup>−63</sup>.
- So the largest finite value is +(2−2<sup>−63</sup>)•2<sup>16,383</sup> = 2<sup>16,384</sup>−2<sup>16,320</sup>.

This matches Intel’s 80-bit floating-point format. You can confirm by including `<float.h>` and printing the values of `FLT_RADIX` (should be 2), `LDBL_MANT_DIG` (64), `LDBL_MIN_EXP` (−16,381), and `LDBL_MAX_EXP` (16,384). (The C exponents are off by one from the IEEE-754 exponents because C scales significands for a [½, 1) normal range.)

Answer (score 2):

There are three common implementations for long double: 1. The boring one where long double is the same as double. 2. The IEEE 754 one where long double is stored with a 15 bit exponent and 64 bit mantissa. 3. An interesting one where long double is stored as the same of two double numbers x + y with the property that round (x + y) = x.

In the first and third case, long double will usually have about 308 digits, just like double. In the second case, long double is capable of holding over 4,900 digits.

Comment: where can I read more on these different common implementations?

Comment: The first one is obvious. The second google for "ieee 754" or "extended precision". The third one look for IBM documents for PowerPC / POWER architecture; it was the method used by Macs before they switched from PowerPC to Intel processors around 2006.

Comment: @computronium  read also about big number arithmetics, in the book of Paul Zimmermann/

Comment: @alinsoar which one? there are several. And they all seem to be about football!

Comment: @computronium https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/ https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/mca/mca-cup-0.5.9.pdf

Answer (score 1):

this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) can help you figure out

float is 32bit size or 4 bytes
there is no long float, alternative name for float is Single in other languages like C#
double have size of 8 bytes and long douuble is 16 bytes

for print values you can use this code

```
printf("%f", _float_var);
printf("%lf", _double_var);
printf("%Lf", _long_double_var);
```

this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) describe how long double store and how you can calculate min and max by your self to make sure

some of values that can store in long double

```
2−16382 × 2−112 = 2−16494
≈ 6.4751751194380251109244389582276465525 × 10−4966
                                            (smallest positive subnormal number)
```

```
2−16382 × (1 − 2−112)
≈ 3.3621031431120935062626778173217519551 × 10−4932
                                            (largest subnormal number)
```

```
2−16382
≈ 3.3621031431120935062626778173217526026 × 10−4932
                                            (smallest positive normal number)
```

```
216383 × (2 − 2−112)
≈ 1.1897314953572317650857593266280070162 × 104932
                                            (largest normal number)
```

```
= 1 − 2−113
≈ 0.9999999999999999999999999999999999037
                                            (largest number less than one)
```

```
1 + 2−112
≈ 1.0000000000000000000000000000000001926
                                            (smallest number larger than one)
```

Comment: Note that the `printf()` conversion specifiers `"%f"` and `"%lf"` are 100% absolutely identical (since C99; `"%lf"` was not described by C90). No function with `...` in the prototype takes a `float` value as they are automatically converted to type `double` before the function is called.

Comment: yes printf is base on what system and what compiler is that you use
i prefer to use my own function to convert float, double or other types to string and then print them

Comment: Your link shows _one_ possibility how long double might be stored, which is currently very, very rarely used and has no hardwore support on most architecture.